# How to transfer database from one mongodb account(1 gmail id) to another, in mongo atlas?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

**I created one mongodb atlas account with one gmail id and another with another gmail id, Now what I want is to transfer database from one account to another**
*One bruteforce method is to get all data with mongodb.find() and push to respective cluster in another account*
But can you give me some better inbuild feature of mongodb atlas?
**Nothing, project name, project owner, organisation is not same in both accounts.**

Answer (score 2):

I got it, what I did was I dump my database(create a backup) using `mongodump` command and then I restore it using `mongorestore` to the another account. You cannot use mongoshell with it, you need to install a mongodatabase tool to perform this operation.